# Python WWW macro

Tags: python, screen-scraping

i need something like iMacros for Python. It would be great to have something like that:

```
browse_to('www.google.com')
type_in_input('search', 'query')
click_button('search')
list = get_all('<p>')
```

Do you know something like that?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost a direct fulfillment of the wishes in the question - [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/).

> twill is a simple language that allows users to browse the Web from a command-line interface. With twill, you can navigate through Web sites that use forms, cookies, and most standard Web features.
>
> twill supports automated Web testing and has a simple Python interface.

(`pyparsing`, `mechanize`, and `BeautifulSoup` are included with twill for convenience.)

A `Python API` example:

```
from twill.commands import go, showforms, formclear, fv, submit

go('http://issola.caltech.edu/~t/qwsgi/qwsgi-demo.cgi/')
go('./widgets')
showforms()

formclear('1')
fv("1", "name", "test")
fv("1", "password", "testpass")
fv("1", "confirm", "yes")
showforms()

submit('0')
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). Other than executing JavaScript in a page, it's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is writing your own script. It's actually not too tough once you get the hang of it, and without invoking a half dozen huge libraries it might even be faster (but I'm not sure). I use a web debugger called "Charles" to surf websites that I want to scrape. It logs all outgoing/incoming http communications, and I use the records to reverse engineer the query strings. Manipulating them in python makes for quite speedy, flexible scraping.