# upload file with Python Mechanize

Tags: python, file, forms, upload, mechanize

When I run the following script:

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="edit_form")
br['file'] = 'file.txt'
br.submit()
```

I get: *ValueError: value attribute is readonly*

And I still get the same error when I add:

```
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
```

So, how can I use Python Mechanize to interact with a HTML form to upload a file?

Richard

Comment: this may be stupid, but does the file.txt exist in your script's working directory?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how to do it properly with Mechanize:

```
br.form.add_file(open(filename), 'text/plain', filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`twill`](http://twill.idyll.org/) is built on `mechanize` and makes scripting web forms a breeze. See [python-www-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294862/python-www-macro).

```
>>> from twill import commands
>>> print commands.formfile.__doc__

>> formfile <form> <field> <filename> [ <content_type> ]

Upload a file via an "upload file" form field.

>>>
```