# How can I use Python with Mechanize for posting multipart/form-data?

Tags: python, mechanize, multipartform-data

I am using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.1.11 for programmatic web browsing, I want to be able to upload files to servers the same way the browser does (by sending the content as multipart/form-data, defined in RFC2388)

Is this possible with mechanize, can you show me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of good answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299855/upload-file-with-python-mechanize), one with bare mechanize and one with twill on top of it, and I believe they both end up sending multipart/form-data as you want.